# Does MAX Q during rocket launch only say that rocket experiences max dynamic pressure?

Tags: launch, rockets, ascent, max-q

I know that during rocket launch, one main event that occurs is MAX Q where the rocket experiences maximum dynamic pressure which is simply (1/2)ρv^2. I also know that drag coefficient of rocket increases drastically as it approaches Mach 1 and drops later. So my question is, does MAX Q also signify the rocket's speed crossing Mach 1 (becoming supersonic) ?

Answer (score 10):

Generally no, max Q is typically well above mach 1. (I think there’s another question about this on the site.) Dynamic pressure is proportional to velocity squared, so speed rather than drag coefficient dominates the pressure curve.